# Placing objects right in front of camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I am trying to figure out how to modify HelloARController.cs from the example ARCore scene to place objects directly in front of the camera. My thinking is that we are raycasting from the camera to a Vector3 on an anchor or tracked plane, so can't we get the Vector3 of the start of that ray and place an object at or near that point?

[I have tried lots, and although I am somewhat a beginner, I have come up with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOKw2.png)

From my understanding, ScreenToWorldPoint should output a vector3 of the screen position corresponding to the world, but it is not working correctly. I have tried other options instead of ScreenToWorldPoint, but nothing has presented the desired effect. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: "but it is not working correctly" - What was your expectation VS what is happening? --- We can't read minds, and we can't know what "not working correctly" means without explanation.

Comment: Also, if you just want something centered in front of the camera, is there any reason not to simply use the camera's `transform.localPosition + offsetZ`?

Comment: Lastly, don't use images to portray code... ***Ever***... Preferably paste the code here (with proper formating), or at the very least post to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/), [github gist](https://gist.github.com/), or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I am new here. transform.local position is already a big step in the right direction, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help!  --- Don't forget to update the question to make the problem clearer, so that we can help you further; and if you find a solution on your own, you can post an answer to your own question; it will help future users with a similar problem.

Comment: I am figuring this out and will update when I get it! i was using the camera local position but it was only spawning objects at the position of the camera when first launching the app. So, now I am going to try using Frame.pose.position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place the object right at the middle of the camera's view, you would have to change the target gameObject's transform.position (as AlmightyR has said).

The ready code would look something like this:

```
GameObject camera;
GameObject object;
float distance = 1;

object.transform.position = camera.transform.position + camera.transform.forward * distance;
```

Since camera's forward component (Z axis) is always poiting at the direction where Camera is looking to, you take that vector's direction and multiply it by a distance you want your object to be placed on. If you want your object to always stay at that position no matter how camera moves, you can make it a child of camera's transform.

```
object.transform.SetParent(camera.transform);
object.transform.localPosition = Vector3.forward * distance;
```

Comment: moving this note to an answer.

Comment: @Arman This code works good.But the object added at center first after 2 or 3 seconds move to position up.I want to place at position at first itself

Answer (score 0):

Arman's suggestion works. Also giving credit to AlmightyR since they got me started in the right direction. Here's what I have now:

```
// Set a position in front of the camera
float distance = 1;
Vector3 cameraPoint = m_firstPersonCamera.transform.position + m_firstPersonCamera.transform.forward * distance;

// Intanstiate an Andy Android object as a child of the anchor; it's transform will now benefit
// from the anchor's tracking.
var andyObject = Instantiate(m_andyAndroidPrefab, cameraPoint, Quaternion.identity,anchor.transform);
```

The only problem with this is that because of the existing HelloAR example code, an object is only placed if you click on a point in the point cloud in my case (or a point on a plane by default). I would like it to behave so that you click anywhere on screen, and it places an object anchored to a nearby point in the point cloud, not necessarily one that you clicked. Any thoughts for how to do that?

*Side tip for those who don't know*: If you want to place something anchored to a point in the cloud, instead of on a plane, change

```
TrackableHitFlag raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlag.PlaneWithinBounds | TrackableHitFlag.PlaneWithinPolygon;
```

to

```
TrackableHitFlag raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlag.PointCloud;
```